# Bug in Mathematica 11.2 WSTP onwards - wstp.h defines only MLEvaluateString?

Tags: bugs, mathlink-or-wstp, headers-footers

**Bug introduced in 11.2 and persisting through 11.3**

---

I maintain a C++ library with a WSTP interface to Mathematica. Some of my users have noticed that in Mathematica versions 11.2 and 11.3, they see a compilation error that `WSEvaluateString` isn't defined. Some compilers hint that it might be a typo for `MLEvaluateString`. This puzzled me, as I thought that `MLEvaluateString` was deprecated, as it had been replaced by `WSEvaluateString` during the MathLink to WSTP rebrand. This is also mentioned [in the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/MLEvaluateString.html).

So I checked the `wstp.h` header file for a few recent versions of Mathematica. I don't have access to them all, let alone a change log! I noticed that in Mathematica 11.1, `wstp.h` indeed defines `WSEvaluateString`. But in Mathematica 11.3, it contains only `MLEvaluateString`.

There's also a new `_REBRAND_H_` block in the 11.3 `wstp.h` header file, that uses macros to make aliases between `WS` and `ML` function names. But there isn't one for `WSEvaluateString`.

---

Wolfram technical support confirmed that it was a bug affecting 11.2 onwards. Are there any ways to circumvent build problems in C callers using e.g., preprocessor macros?

Comment: How much of `wstp.h` am I allowed to quote in my question?

Comment: I can confirm the difference you're seeing between 11.1 and 11.3.  I think you should report this to tech support as well.

Comment: OK, I have reported it directly to Mathematica support.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the `wstp.h` header file uses a macro to indicate the Mathematica version. I had hoped to use it to write a work-around for this bug. However, there were two problems.

1. The version number defined by the macro doesn't correspond to the actual Mathematica version. Perhaps this is a another bug. E.g., my Mathematica 11.1 `wstp.h` contains `#define WSMATHVERSION 10.0.0`.
2. The format of the version number makes it difficult to use. See e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915355/using-macros-that-define-version-numbers-in-the-form-10-0-0).

The 11.2 and 11.3 `wstp.h` header files define aliases to `WS` function names in a block surrounded by a header guard (perhaps this was once a separate header file).  The name of the header guard is `_REBRAND_H_`. Thus I use that macro to judge whether the `wstp.h` is an 11.2 or 11.3 one affected by the bug,

```
#ifdef _REBRAND_H_   
#define EVALSTRING MLEvaluateString
#else
#define EVALSTRING WSEvaluateString
#endif
```

This should work for now, but probably won't work when this bug is addressed in the future (presumably in 11.4).